# Correct usage of \D in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have some code where I am trying to find a certain set of numbers. The length varies and I do not want them to be found amongst other numbers. For example the following code:

```
reg="\D12345\D"
string="12345"
matchedResults = re.finditer(reg, string)

for match in matchedResults:
    print match.group(0)
```

Does not work if the number is just by itself. However this will work if I put:

```
string="a12345"
```

but this will also match the a which is undesirable. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: give us a few examples of the strings you want to match please

Comment: @Jayram \d and \D are different patterns, so it can't be a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use zero-width negative look-around assertions:

```
reg = r"(?<!\d)12345(?!\d)"
```

The look-around assertions (lookbehind and lookahead) match a *position*, not a character; the negative assertions only match if the preceding text or the following text respectively does *not* match the named pattern.

This means only locations that do *not* follow or precede a number will be matched; the start and end of a string will do for that purpose.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> reg = re.compile(r"(?<!\d)12345(?!\d)")
>>> reg.search('12345')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x102981ac0>
>>> reg.search('-12345-')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x102a51238>
>>> reg.search('0123456')
>>> reg.search('012345-')
>>> reg.search('-123456')
```

Comment: I thought about that but then I dont get a match if the number has characters before it. For example I would like it to match with an = before it with no spaces.
Edit: After your edit that works perfect, thankyou.

Comment: Could you explain what each element in (?<!\d) is actually doing? Will help with my understanding and future use. Thanks

Comment: @Martyn: I tried to in my answer. Each 'statement' in a regular expression either matches a character (literally or by a pattern) or it matches a location (anchors, like `^` and `$` and `\b`). Positive lookaround assertions match a position too, but only if the pattern they contain was matched *before* or *after* their position.

Comment: @Martyn: For example, `(?=Asimov)` matches only those positions in an input text where the literal text `Asimov` *follows*. Negative look-around only matches if the pattern does *not* match.

Comment: @Martyn: So, `(?<!\d)` matches *any* position in the text where there was *not* a digit just before it. Combined with other patterns, that makes it very easy to say that those other patterns should *not* follow a digit.

Comment: Ok so I can assume that !\d means not a digit. The < im guessing means before, but what does the question mark refer to?

Comment: @Martyn: No, the `(?<!...)` is the whole operator. It's positive equivalent is `(?<...)`, and look-ahead is `(?!...)` and `(?=...)`.